# Teamcity ERROR MESSAGE for Server Url?

Tags: teamcity

I am setup teamcity on my windows 7 laptop. I can connect to it on the server with the windows tray notifier. When I try to connect to it from another machine, i get the "Server URL IS INVALID ERROR? Please Help!

Comment: What is Teamcity? And this probably belongs on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows 7 laptop probably doesn't allow incoming traffic to TeamCity from other machines. You can use the Windows Firewall configuration to allow it.

Also, isn't this the same question as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751761/i-need-the-correct-teamcity-windows-tray-notfier-url

Also, this may get better reception on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)!